# Jquery mobile is not applying styles when the page is dynamically added

Tags: jquery-mobile, sammy.js

Hi I have a small app that uses JQM and Sammy. I am using Sammy to load pages dynamically and appending to the body of my index.html. the problem is i dont see the JQM themes are getting applied and there are no errors in console as well.

Are there any reason for this. I do call the following

```
 context.render('view/abc.template')
                .appendTo(context.$element(),function(){
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#container").trigger('pagecreate');
                    });
                });
```

Thanks

Comment: remove `.ready` its not designed for jQM. Once you append pages into DOM, they will get enhanced before being shown. Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9jc8Y/

Comment: Thanks Omar, i make the changes and now i could see the JQM styles being applied for the first template but when i move to the next page which is again a template and being rendered using sammy the styles are not getting rendered for it. Any idea what could be reason ?

Comment: try adding `$('[data-role=page').page();` or `$('[data-role=page').trigger('pagecreate');`

Comment: I added it after i append my template to dom but no luck. JQM styles are still not getting applied. For your referrence below is the code  this.get('#/item', function(context) {
             context.app.swap('');
             context.render('view/page2.template')
                 .appendTo(context.$element(),function(){
                  //   $(document).ready(function () {
                  //       $("#page2").trigger('pagecreate');
                   //  });
                 });

             $('[data-role="page"]').page();

         });

Comment: where do you append pages? try `$.mobile.pageContainer.append('your data')`

Comment: Hi Omar i am not using jquery mobile navigation i am using sammyjs for navigation. My views are all template based. So every time there is an action i load a template and this templates are nothing but jquery-mobile pages. i have disabled the default ajax navigation for jquery mobile. Do i need to enable it if want use $.mobile.pageContainer.append('your data')

Comment: This is not navigation, `pageContainer` is the document body, where you should append pages.

Comment: Ok please see my sample code and let me know if anythig needs tobe change in that  this.get('#/item', function(context) {
             context.app.swap('');

             context.render('view/page2.template')
                 .appendTo(context.$element(),function(){
                  //   $(document).ready(function () {
                  //       $("#page2").trigger('pagecreate');
                   //  });
                 });

             $('[data-role="page"]').page();

         });

Comment: I dont know what's `context.$element()` is..is it a normal div? is it a page? rendering dynamic items depends on their type (`data-role`).

Comment: context.element is the body where i try to append the templates dynamically. The templates are itself has been treated as separate page with data-role=page

Comment: Those templates have data-role=page?

Comment: yes they do have it but looks like the issue is with sammyjs that i am using for page transition/navigation. The last development that i had is i was able to load the first template with jqm styles applied but when i go to the next the styles are not loading. But if i take the url dirctly for second template and paste it in browser. The styls are shown. I am stuck into it not sure whats the reason

Comment: Then use `$('[data-role=page]').page();` or `$('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate');` after inserting new template/page.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it;

1) firstly I disabled my JQM routing like so in a file called plugins.js;

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    /**
    * check out http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/  for more details
    */
   $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
   $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
   $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
   $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
```

This code was loaded before I loaded JQM, like so;

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/sammy/sammy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/sammy/plugins/sammy.template.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Then my main.js function looks like this;

```
(function($) {

    var app = $.sammy('#main', function() {
        this.use('Template');

        this.get('#/', function(context) {
            context.load('/templates/index.template', function() {
                $("#container").trigger('pagecreate');
            }).appendTo(context.$element());
        });

        this.get('#/landing', function(context) {
            context.load('/templates/landing.template', function() {
                $("#container").trigger('pagecreate');
            }).replace(context.$element());
        });

    });

    $(function() {
        app.run('#/');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I think you are not far off on your code snippet above.  NB you have your $(document).ready function as a callback to appendTo, which does not take a callback.  You will see mine is in load() which does

Comment: Thanks Paul. Could i ask you to share your index.html and the templates i am getting an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined  with the same code not sure what is the reason.

Comment: landing template is here https://gist.github.com/sharpred/05969c0d54e491c1af63

I would just share the project with you, but it is for a customer and subject to NDA

Comment: one thought: are you loading the sammy.template plugin as above?

Comment: Thanks for the response Paul, I am able to load the template now with two issues. First one is the page transition is not smooth even though i have added the page transition slide next one from the second page when i come back to first page i am seeing the content of both the pages because if you see the code ,we are actually appending not replacing if it is first page. have you faced similar issue ? Does Jquery  mobile has some inbuilt settings to achieve that

Comment: Hi Paul,apologize for late response. I did tried tat and it worked. Thanks a lot. Now i am trying to load the template in a different way. Right now we have defined the data-role=page in index.html and loading the content dynamically. Is it possible to leave the index.html empty that is only head and body tag and have the templates be the realpage. The reason i am trying this is i need some event to be triggered whenever the page changes but i dont see that "pagecreate" event is triggered as the page is already created. Once again appreciate your input.